# Wordpress wp_insert_post(); to different installations in one Script

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, multiple-instances

Imagine i have a big set of preformatted data and want to create wordpress posts out of it.

What i need is just some little snippet how to:

1. check if there is a wordpress connection (weather wp-blog-header.php is included or not)
2. close wordpress database connection
3. include("wp-blog-header");
4. insert post

i would do like so... is this a way i can go?

```
$data = array(
                    "path/to/wordpress-instance/wp-blog-header.php" => array(
                        "post_title" => "bla",
                        "post_content" => "blubb"
                        ...
                    ),
                    "path/to/wordpress-instance/wp-blog-header.php" => array(
                        "post_title" => "bla",
                        "post_content" => "blubb"
                            ...
                    ),
                    "path/to/wordpress-instance/wp-blog-header.php" => array(
                        "post_title" => "bla",
                        "post_content" => "blubb"
                            ...
                    )
                );



                foreach($data as $path => $dataItem){

                    if($wpdb){
                        @mysql_close( $wpdb->dbh );//close connection
                    }

                    include($path);//new wp-blog-header

                    wp_insert_post($dataItem);


                }
```

Comment: i ask this because i can´t really test it and want to be sure if this can be done so

Comment: Now i just uploaded it and my error_log sais like the following PHP Warning:  mysql_errno(): 43 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /path/to/wordpress-instance/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531... any help? :)

Comment: could it be to fast for mySQL? Should i include all wp-blog-header.php in teh beginning and then use it afterwards? But how can i change the $wpdb variable for each instance, in order to use the right connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that sounds like a roundabout way of doing things.  why bother shutting down the db connection in the first place?

instead, just create a page in wp.  then create a page template that runs php code for that page.

instead of printing any data from the database for that page, just loop through and print whatever data you want.  (so you don't need any sort of wp_query loop).

if you want to pass parameters to determine which page to show, you can setup your urls like:

```
http://example.com/the_page/some_parameter
```

then use php to parse the url, get the parameter and display the correct page.

Comment: this doesn´t work for me because i want to save the data into the wordpress tables

Comment: You can use something like the Pods plugin to help create and manage custom wordpress tables for custom post types.  Then in the page template I mentioned, you would have a pods loop to go through your custom data.

Comment: yes.. that would be a way... would have been nice to avoid it because the extra work but this would definatly working ...thanks 2 you